# Minimise $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + x_i}$ subject to constraint using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization

Minimise $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + x_i}$ subject to $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i =b$, $x_i\geq 0$ for $i=1,\cdots , n$, where $a_i >0$ for $i=1,\cdots , n$ and $b>0$.

I know I need to use Lagrange multipliers to do this, but I'm having difficulty getting the calculation to work. In particular, I am confused about what the set $Y=\{\lambda: inf_{x\geq 0}L(x, \lambda)>-\infty\}$ is. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem reads:
\begin{align}
\min_{x_i,~i=1,\ldots,n}~& \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i+x_i}\\
s.t.~& \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=b\\
& x_i\geq 0,~\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}
\end{align}

Let $\lambda$ be the Lagrange multiplier associated with the equality constraint and $\mu_i\leq 0,~i=1,\ldots,n$ be the Lagrange multipliers associated with the inequality constraints. The Lagrangian of the problem reads:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\lambda,\mathbf{\mu})=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i+x_i}+\lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-b\right)+\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i x_i
\end{equation}
The KKT conditions are:
\begin{align}
\mu_i&=\frac{1}{(a_i+x_i)^2}-\lambda,~\forall i\\
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i&=b\\
x_i&\geq 0,~\forall i\\
\mu_i&\leq 0,~\forall i\\
\mu_ix_i&=0,~\forall i
\end{align}
The first condition corresponds to $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_i}=0,~\forall i$, the second and third to the primal feasibility, the fourth to dual feasibility and the fifth is the complementary slackness condition.
Substituting the first condition in the last yields:
\begin{equation}
x_i\left(\frac{1}{(a_i+x_i)^2}-\lambda\right)=0
\end{equation}

Consider a fixed index $k$:

- If $a_k<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$, then the condition that $\mu_k\leq 0$ implies that we must have $x_k>0$ in order to satisfy the first condition, which in turn implies that we must have $x_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}-a_k$ in order to satisfy the complementary slackness condition.
- If $a_k\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$, then the complementary slackness condition can only be satisfied if $x_k=0$

We have thus shown that:
$$
x_k=
\begin{cases}
0 & a_k\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}},\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}-a_k & a_k<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}
\end{cases}
$$

Finally, you can find $\lambda$ by using the second KKT condition, which reads:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \max\left(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}-a_k\right)=b
$$
The sum on the left is a continuous and piecewise differentiable function with break-points at the $1/a_k^2$.

This problem is very closely related to the Water-filling problem, which you can find for instance in Stephen Boyd's [Convex Optimization](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) book, page 245.

The interpretation of the problem is that you start allocating your budget to the indices of lower $a_k$, and that all indices to which some of the budget has been allocated have a common $a_k+x_k$ value. Whenever this common level reaches a new value $a_{k'}$, you also start allocating budget to the index $k'$ and so on, until you run out of budget.

**Edit**

As an illustration, I have let $n=20$ and generated random values for the $a_i$ in the interval $[1,50]$. I have let $b=150$ and solved the problem as described above. The following graph sums up the results:

[image]

You can observe that the indices are filled up to the level $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ (whenever that makes sense). You can play with the following code that I used to generate the picture.

```
M=50;
n=20;
a=randi(M,1,n);
b=150;
g=@(lam) sum(max(0,1./sqrt(lam)-a))-b;
lambda=fzero(g,0.001);
x=max(0,1./sqrt(lambda)-a);

bar(a+x)
hold on
bar(a,'green')
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, is your nickname a reference to the West Wing character?

Comment: Yes, well spotted - he's my favourite tv show character, on what is probably one of my favourite tv shows!